# SQL doesnt work when in my code but does work when in a query

Tags: c#

So when I run this code inside of my C# programme it returns false. Yet when I return it inside of the query designer in visual studio it returns the correct value.

```
private void GetUserELO(int UserID, ref double Elo)
    {
        clsDBConnector dbConnector = new clsDBConnector();
        OleDbDataReader dr;
        string sqlStr;
        dbConnector.Connect();
        sqlStr = "SELECT Users.Elo FROM Users WHERE UserID = " + UserID + "";
        dr = dbConnector.DoSQL(sqlStr);
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            string Elo1 = Convert.ToString(dr.Read());
            MessageBox.Show("User Added" + UserID, "Sucessfully Added User" + 
            Elo1,
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
        }
    }
```

Please ignore the message box that is just to show me the output.

Comment: How about you show us the magic in `dbConnector.DoSQL`

Comment: You are calling `Read` on what I think is a DataReader. You don't want to do that, as it advances to the next record rather than returning a value - you would use `string Elo1 = dr.GetString(0);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making 2 calls to `dr.Read()` in each iteration. You must make only one.
Use the `GetValue` for accessing the column result and `Read` to fetch the next record.

```
private void GetUserELO(int UserID, ref double Elo)
    {
        clsDBConnector dbConnector = new clsDBConnector();
        OleDbDataReader dr;
        string sqlStr;
        dbConnector.Connect();
        sqlStr = "SELECT Users.Elo FROM Users WHERE UserID = " + UserID + "";
        dr = dbConnector.DoSQL(sqlStr);
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            string Elo1 = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
            MessageBox.Show("User Added" + UserID, "Sucessfully Added User" + 
            Elo1,
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
        }
    }
```

Comment: THANK YOU! You fixed it you are a saviour!

Comment: Please, mark the answer as the correct, and vote for it, thanks

Comment: I marked it but cant upvote it due to being a new member. But seriously a massive thank you!